# R: return "1.0" from FUN(1.01)?

Tags: string, r, xtable

I would like to convert a number to a specified number of significant figures, e.g. some function that returns `"1.0"` (as a character) from `FUN(1.01)`. (I need a character because the value will be used in an `xtable`.

I suspect that this is trivial, but I am having trouble.

Here is what I have tried:

```
> signif(1.01, 2)
[1] 1
> round(1.01, 2)
[1] 1.01
> format(1.01, digits = 2)
[1] "1"
> as.character(trunc(1.20, 3))
[1] "1"
> as.character(round(1.01, digits = 2))
[1] "1"
```

Is there a function that will do this?

Comment: sorry removed my comment before your edit and comment as I quickly realized this was a problem. Joshua gives a nice solution.

Comment: Are you aware that when you print an xtable you can set the number of digits? It can include padding zeroes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `?sprintf`:

```
> sprintf("%0.1f", 1.01)
[1] "1.0"
```

There's also `format` and `formatC`, which you may find more user-friendly:

```
> format(1.01,digits=1,nsmall=1)
[1] "1.0"
> formatC(1.01,digits=1,format="f")
[1] "1.0"
```

Comment: that is helpful, but it doesn't take `1.01` as an argument

Comment: can you please explain how this works? the documentation `?sprint` is sparse.

Comment: @Abe, You call that sparse?!! Have you worked through the examples in `?sprintf`?

Comment: @Abe: your solution only works by chance.  `1.01` should be the second argument to `sprintf`.

Comment: @GSee no, I just looked at the `usage` and found the `fmt` argument `arguments`, and only got as far as the fact that `?fmt` and `help.search("fmt")` return nothing.

Comment: I definitely prefer format, as neither it nor formatC require that crazy %0.1f stuff.